# jquery Telephone Format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to output user inputted value of 1234567890 to be displayed as 123-456-7890. With the below code, the output is as expected however when you trying to edit the number, there are weird issues. Can someone please help.

```js
$("input[type='tel']").keyup(function() {
  if (this.value.length === 10) {
    var number = this.value
    this.value = number.substring(0, 3) + '-' + number.substring(3, 6) + '-' + number.substring(6, 10)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="e.g.: 111-222-3333" type="tel" maxlength="10" />
```

Comment: Define _'weird issues'_

Comment: It also doesn't work if the user types in the hyphens as your "e.g." suggests they do.  You could write a lot of complicated code to handle all variations and edits, but wouldn't it be simpler to just have 3 separate text fields `[111]-[222]-[3333]` and have it tab automatically between them as the user types?  You can also check that they're numeric as they're entered.

Comment: Why don´t you try a jQuery Mask Plugin? Like this one for example
http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not removing the "-" from the previous value. So when the keyup event is fired, the value has the - from the previous keyup parse event.

Why don´t you remove the "-" from the string, and then run your substring code?

It'd look like

```js
$("input[type='tel']").keyup(function() {
  if (this.value.length === 10) {
    var number = this.value.replace('-', '');
    this.value = number.substring(0, 3) + '-' + number.substring(3, 6) + '-' + number.substring(6, 10)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are easier ways to accomplish this but, I hope this helps.

```js
$("input[type='tel']").keyup(function() {
  
  
   if (this.value.length == 10) {
       var number = this.value
    this.value = number.substring(0, 3) + '-' + number.substring(3, 6) + '-' + number.substring(6, 10)
    }
    else if (this.value.indexOf('-') >= 0) 
    {   
        if (this.value.length != 12) {
        this.value = this.value.replace( /-/g, '' );
          }
    }
  
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="e.g.: 111-222-3333" type="tel" maxlength="10" />
```